# Adding a level to htaccess redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect any URL ending with `.html` like so

```
example.com/article-title.html
```

to

```
example.com/subfolder/article-title.html
```

This part should match all `.html` URLs, but I can't figure out how to add the `/subfolder/` part.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$
```

What should I write after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.html$ /subfolder/$1.html [R,L]
```

This would redirect `/foobar.html` to `/subfolder/foobar.html` .

Comment: Gosh, that's a lot better than my kludge, which is to create a symbolic link called whatever.html that points to subfolder/whatever.html  (just j/k)